# Low accuracy i.e. 52% in predicting whereas the training and validation accuracy during training is around 92%

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I'm using pre-trained VGG19 to train the model. While training I'm getting good accuracy around 92% (both training and validation).

```
vgg19 = VGG19(input_shape=IMAGE_SIZE, weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
for layer in vgg19.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

x = Flatten()(vgg19.output)
prediction = Dense(len(folders), activation='softmax')(x)
model = Model(inputs=vgg19.input, outputs=prediction)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
  optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(
    learning_rate=0.0005,
    name="Adam"),
  metrics=['accuracy']
)

r = model.fit_generator(
  training_set,
  validation_data=test_set,
  epochs=20,
  steps_per_epoch=len(training_set),
  validation_steps=len(test_set)
)

predictions = model.predict(test_set, steps = test_set.n // 31, verbose=1)

y_pred = []
for i in predictions:
  y_pred.append(int(np.argmax(i)))
y_pred = np.asarray(y_pred)
```

The accuracy while training can be viewed from here.[image: Training and Validation Loss and Accuracy]

However, while predicting, I'm getting an accuracy of 52.33% only.

Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong here?
Thank you!

Comment: I think you have an overfitting problem. You can use several methods to prevent overfitting your data. 
Use regularization or dropout 
Also, you can reduce the number of neurons or layers.
Also, early stopping can be a good idea

Comment: Hey, validation accuracy and loss are fine. I'm talking about the accuracy I'm getting by model.predict(). Why it is just 52%? On the other hand, validation accuracy is around 90%, this doesn't seem like an overfitting problem to me. Please, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Have you normalized your test data?

Comment: Yes, its normalized.

Comment: Here is a useful link: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48718663/validation-and-testing-accuracy-widely-different

Comment: I hope it will help you ...

Comment: I'm a bit confused - "validation accuracy and loss are fine [...] why is it just 52%? On the other hand, validation accuracy is around 90%". How is this understood?

Comment: I mean to say that while training the model, validation accuracy and loss is close to that of training. But when I predict the classes for the test set using the model.predict(), I get an accuracy of around 52%. I apologize for being confusing.

Comment: Some suggestions that I experienced before maybe it helps: 1. Be careful how you choose data for validation and test. Maybe your validation data is very similar to your train data. 2. Make sure you are using the same preprocessing for your test data. Its a common mistake. 3. Try to evaluate test data (predict) manually. Meaning dont use model.predict().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this is:

```
test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('/content/drive/MyDrive/dataset/Test',
                                            target_size = (224, 224),
                                            batch_size = 32,
                                            class_mode = 'categorical',
                                            shuffle=False)
```

I was not adding `shuffle=False` in the `flow_from_directory` which by default kept `shuffle=True` and that is the reason I was getting low accuracy while predicting.

I hope it will help anyone doing the same mistake!

Answer (score 0):

It seems your algorithm lacks generalisation. One reason can be the size of the dataset you have used for training. larger dataset, better generalisation